# How can I exclude a folder from an Artifact Path on TeamCity?

Tags: build, teamcity, artifact

I have an **Artifact path** like the following:

```
%system.teamcity.build.workingDir%\Presentation\obj\Release\Package=>Package.zip
```

But I need to exclude a folder from "Package", I´ve tried things like:

```
%system.teamcity.build.workingDir%\Presentation\obj\Release\Package
-:%system.teamcity.build.workingDir%\Presentation\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp
-:Package\PackageTmp
```

But nothing seems to work, any ideas ?

Greetings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exclusion patterns are not supported yet for artifact paths. There is an [issue in TeamCity tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-5244) requesting this functionality. Please watch/vote.

Additionally, there is [this workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12780656/256776). Have a look, if it fits your needs

Comment: What if I need to select specific files and .zip them ?
I mean, I would select them but the folder I don´t need

Comment: You can define patterns for these files explicitly:
./file1.txt=>archive.zip
./dir1/dir2/file2.exe=>archive.zip

such pattern would result in archive.zip being published and containing 'file1.txt' and 'file2.exe' on its top level

Comment: In TeamCity v10 this has been fixed:
https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Configuring+General+Settings#ConfiguringGeneralSettings-artifactPaths